# Python - Update loop with latest files during runtime

Tags: for-loop

Is there a best way to keep checking the current directory for the updated files and add that updated file to the loop during runtime?

Code I have tried:

```
list = os.listdir(folder)
    #[A1.txt,B1.txt,C1.txt,D1.txt]  #add E1.txt
       for i in list:
          time.sleep(10)
          with open(folder + i, "rb") as readdata:
             print("The executing file is:", i)
             data = readdata.read()
                    
Current Output:
('The executing file is:', 'A1.txt')
('The executing file is:', 'B1.txt')
('The executing file is:', 'C1.txt')
('The executing file is:', 'D1.txt')
            
Expected Output:
('The executing file is:', 'A1.txt')
('The executing file is:', 'B1.txt')
('The executing file is:', 'C1.txt')
('The executing file is:', 'D1.txt')
('The executing file is:', 'E1.txt')
```

Comment: have same issue, any help